# URL Regex For HTTP/HTTPS is optional

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Hi I am using Following URL regex for finding web site urls.

```
 NSString *urlRegEx =@"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
```

But I need to find following URL's too.

Examples:

> www.gmail.com
>
> gmail.com
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Like this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using another "or" `|` after `(http|https)://`:

```
(http|https)://|((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+
```

That should find all of the examples you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make your first part optional:

```
((http|https)://)?
```

However you've also got a few errors in your expression, so it matches more than it should. You've used `|` and escaped `.` inside `[ ]`, all that does is add `|` and `\` to the set. Fixing that and simplifying gives:

```
(https?://)?(\w|[-_0-9])+([./](\w|[-_0-9])+)+
```

HTH